# Regular Eacepretion in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hi I am trying to make a `Regular expression` to replace any word with bound `(#)` sing to a URL

I just want it like twitter , I have made it for English language 
but when the post in another language then it will be problem 
I want it accept any word from any language.

My current `REGEX` :

```
"/#+([A-Za-z0-9_\/]+)/";
```

Comment: Can you please provide some examples on what should match and what should not match

Comment: #جافا   #Java    #JAVA3  #جافا3

Comment: `#(\S+)` Will match anything untill a space character is found.

Comment: @user2593913 but `\S` will match also the special chars.

Comment: I have to agree with @AvinashRaj on that one. Although it'll work, his answer is probebly the best way to go. Therefor I won't turn mine into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\p{L}` matches any kind of character from any language.

```
#([\p{L}\d_]+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wN7tX6/1)

Comment: or `#([\p{L}\p{N}_]+)`. use this if you want to include forward slash also `#([\p{L}\d_\/]+)`

Comment: you need to include unicode modifier `u` . `preg_match_all('~regex~u', $str, $match);`

Comment: please can you give an example for that

Comment: In your case that would be `"/#([\p{L}\d_]+)/u"` or `"/#([\p{L}\p{N}_]+)/u"`.